# Algebraic Groups Connected and Reduced?

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Lastly I was a bit surprised about a statement regarding the difference of group schemes to algebraic groups at wiki

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_scheme

Let me quote it: "...  Group schemes arise
naturally as symmetries of schemes, and they generalize algebraic groups, in the sense that all algebraic groups have group scheme
structure, but group schemes ***are not necessarily connected***, smooth, or defined over a field...."

My question is simply why is this provides a distinguishing criterion? Are algebraic groups allways connected? Up to now I never heard that without some extra assumtions (e.g. irreducibility) all algebraic groups are connected. Or do I oversee here a detail?

Futher question: What about beeing reduced? Should algebraic groups always be reduced as varieties? If yes, where does this in their definition flows in?

Comment: You're going to find different definitions in every textbook.  Algebraic groups are usually defined as groups that are also varieties, and it's common for a variety to always be irreducible (thus connected) and reduced.  I'm a little surprised to see "smooth" on the list.

I think "not always defined over a field" is the most important distinction listed, though I'd say "not always finite type over a field" instead, since even group schemes over fields can be quite far from being algebraic groups.

Comment: ...and a variety is for you a scheme over $k$ such that it is
integral (so irred and reduced) and the structure morphism $X \to Spec(k)$ is separated and of finite typ? Sorry, for this definition question, but variety is another candidate which is in defined in quite every ag book in a way far away from uniqueness...

Comment: My point was that almost everybody agrees "algebraic group" = "group object in category of algebraic varieties", but there's some room for disagreement when defining varieties.  The definition you gave is pretty close to my preferred definition, though I might add "geometrically integral" (i.e. the base change to the algebraic closure is integral).

Comment: @Slade Is there any particular reason that you think smoothness is surprising? It's guaranteed in characteristic $0$ if your group is finite type, and in characteristic $p$ the only time I really run into non-smooth groups are dealing with things like connected finite flat group schemes (e.g. $\mu_p$) whose study has a 'different feel' than the study of algebraic groups (which usually means linear algebraic groups or, perhaps, abelian varieties but those are smooth anyways).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *Slade* points out in the comments, this is largely a matter of definition. The basic assumptions that most people make is that your group $G$ is connected and smooth (the latter actually being guaranteed in characteristic $0$ for finite type groups). This automatically implies that $G$ is geometrically integral. To see that it's geometrically connected you can see the discussion of such matters [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3168956/16497) and irreducibility follows from the whole classical "smooth implies local rings are domains" and then "connected plus local rings are domains implies irreducible".

That said, there's actually a fairly convincing argument that one should consider non-connected groups in the sense that really simple groups can quickly give rise to disconnected groups via simple operations.

For example, consider the following well-known theorem:

> **Theorem(Steinberg):** Let $G$ be a (connected) reductive algebraic group over $k=\overline{k}$. Then, the property that for every semisimple $s\in G(k)$ satisfies that $C_G(s)$ (its centralizer) is connected is equivalent to the claim that its derived subgroup $G^\mathrm{der}$ is simply connected.

So, for example, if you are dealing with adjoint groups like $\mathrm{PGL}_n$, then taking centralizers of semisimple elements needn't give you connected groups! As a simple example, convince yourself that if $s:=\begin{pmatrix}-1 & 0\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ then $\pi_0(C_{\mathrm{PGL}_2}(s))=2$.

EDIT: Here's a [reference](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/047N) for the claim that in characteristic 0 group schemes locally of finite type are smooth. The point is that it suffices to show that $G$ is reduced since then generic smoothness gives you a dense open locus of smooth points and then you can use the homogeneity of $G$ to show that all closed points of $G$ are regular, so that $G$ is smooth. The reducedness then comes from a trick/theorem of Cartier.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Following question: Could you give a reference/sketch of the proof that if group scheme $G$ is given over a field $k$ of characteristic $0$ is of finite type then it must be smooth?