# Equivalent definitions of elliptic curves over a scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

I would like to compare the two definitions of elliptic curves over an arbitrary scheme.

**Scholze:** A morphism $p: E \to S$ of schemes with a section $e: S \to E$ such that $p$ is proper, flat, and all geometric fibers are elliptic curves (with zero section given by $e$).

(from *The Langlands-Kottwitz approach for the modular curve*)

**Katz, Mazur:** proper, smooth curve $f:E \to S$ with geometrically connected fibers all of genus one, given with a section $0: S \to E$.

(from *Arithmetic Moduli of Elliptic Curves*)

- Scholze => Katz, Mazur: Do we use the fact that a morphism that is flat, locally of finite presentation, and all fibers smooth, is smooth morphism? If so, how do we show that $p$ is locally of finite presentation?
- Katz, Mazur => Scholze: Fiber of $f:E_s \to Spec(\kappa(s))$ is a proper, smooth, geometrically connected curve of genus one with a section given by $0$.

  1. This becomes projective because $E_s$ is an abelian variety, and proper abelian variety over a field $k$ is projective?
  2. Why do we impose the condition geometrically connected? Isn't the fiber still an elliptic curve over a field with geometrically connected condition?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Spec}{\mathrm{Spec}}$
Scholze---> Katz-Mazur: I really wouldn't stress too much about this, to be honest. Probably Scholze should say that $p$ is locally of finite presentation and/or $S$ is locally Noetherian. Since the moduli spaces of such objects constructed is locally Noetherian, you really have no harm restricting to such a thing. Then, proper implies finite type and since S is locally Noetherian this implies that $p$ is locally of finite presentation. And then, yes, we use 
[Tag01V8][1] If it makes you feel any better, his ultimate goal with this paper, and subsequent ones (which, incidentally, my thesis is a generalization of one of these papers) is to work in the same realm as the work of Harris-Taylor. In Harris-Taylor's seminal book/paper where they prove local Langlands for $\mathrm{GL}_n(F)$ they explicitly restrict only the schemes which are locally Noetherian (as does Kottwitz, if I recall correctly, in his original paper "On the points of some Shimura varieties over finite fields).

Katz-Mazur ---> Scholze: A smooth proper connected curve over a field is automatically projective. We may assume we're over $\overline{k}$. Let $X$ be a smooth proper conneced curve. Let $U$ be an affine open subscheme. Then, by taking a projectivization of $U$ (i.e. locally closed immerse $U$ into some $\mathbb{P}^n$ and take closure) and normalizations you can find an $X'$ which is smooth and projective containing $U$. Then, you get a birational map $X\dashrightarrow X'$. One can then use the valuative criterion to deduce this is an isomorphism.

An elliptic curve is connected. Note then that if $X/k$ is finite type, connected, and $X(k)\ne \varnothing$ then $X$ is automatically geometrically connected. Since any idempotents in $\mathcal{O}(X_{\overline{k}})$ must show up at some finite extension, it suffices to show that $X_L$ is connected for every finite extension $L/k$. Note that since $\Spec(L)\to \Spec(k)$ is flat and finite then same is true for $X_L\to X$, and thus $X_L\to X$ is clopen. Thus, if $C$ is a connected component of $X_L$ it's clopen (since $X_L$ is Noetherian) and thus its image under $X_L\to X$ is clopen, and thus all of $X$. Suppose that there exists another connected component $C'$ of $X_L$. Then, by what we just said the image of $C$ and $C'$ both contain any $x\in X(k)$. Note though that if $\pi:X_L\to X$ is our projection, then $\pi^{-1}(x)$ can be identified set theoretically as $\Spec(L\otimes_k k)=\Spec(L)$ and co consists of one point. This means that $C$ and $C'$, since they both hit $x$, have an intersection point. This is a contradiction. So an elliptic curve, being connected and having $E(k)\ne \varnothing$, is automatically geometrically connected.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply. For the part you said to "not stress too much about", do you mean the following? Since the representing scheme $\mathcal{M}_n$ of moduli space of elliptic curves with "naive" level-$N$-structure is a curve over $\mathrm{Spec}~\mathbb{Z}[1/N]$, the moduli space of elliptic curves (with level-$N$-structure) coincides whether you use Scholze's definition and Katz-Mazur's definition?

Comment: @libofmath Yes, that $\mathcal{M}_n$ is locally Noetherian (not just $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}[1/N]$) so that the representing space for moduli of enhanced elliptic curves lives in the category of locally Noetherian schemes.

Comment: could you loose a couple of words on why in the part showing that smooth proper conn curve over field is projective it can be assumed to work over alg closed field? Do you tacitly use some descent argument, or is in this concrete situation a more 'elementary' reason available why it suffice here to work over 
$\bar{k}$?

Comment: By the way another question: Where in your argument in the middle part you explicitly exploit that you assume to work over alg closed field $k=\overline{k}$? ie why you make this assumtion? If I not missing something your argumentation in the middle part should completely go throught for arbitrary base field $k$ (ie not neccessarily alg closed)?