# smooth proper connected curve over a field is projective

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I have the following question: In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3168956) is remarked that
to show that a smooth proper connected curve $X$ over a field $k$ is projective
we may assume to work over $\overline{k}$.

Why can one make this assumption? And aside from that if we assume we are
working over $\overline{k}$ and follow the presented proof where it makes use of
this assumption?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof given in the link does not need algebraic closure of $k$ - the key steps in the proof are that normalization over a field is a finite morphism, finite morphisms are projective, and the curve to projective extension theorem, none of which use any properties of the base field.

To explain why one can show the claim for $k=\overline{k}$, one may use descent - this is basically the inverse of "stable under base change", where instead of saying "if $f:X\to S$ has property $P$, then the base change $X\times_S S' \to S'$ along $S'\to S$ also has property $P$", we ask the question "if $X\times_S S'\to S'$ has property $P$, must $f$ have property $P$?". It turns out that when $S'\to S$ is nice (in our case, faithfully flat and quasi-compact) that many convenient properties of morphisms, like being a closed immersion, descend. See [Stacks 02L6](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02L6) or EGA IV2, somewhere around 2.7.

Comment: yes the reason for passing to $\bar{k}$ is a bit mysterious. The 
obvious advantage would be that we can then assume that there exist 
$k$-rational points which would even form a dense subset. But as you 
said every step seemingly works over arbitrary base field. 
Perhaps the latter assumption provides a simplification of some
partial argument...